# jQuery Chrome - disable enter key

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, key, enter

I've got a tutorial based web page, where users can advance to the next tutorial page by using arrow href buttons (only if they complete some tasks). Also on most pages the enter key will advance you to the next page.

However, some tutorial pages, use the enter key for different purpose, and i want that key to be disabled. I've done the following:

```
$(window).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    { 
        e.preventDefault();         
        return false;
    }
});
```

which works fine in IE/FF/Opera but it doesnt in chrome.

In chrome, if i add an alert inside if, then the form will not submit. otherwise it will.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

```
$(function () {

        $('form').bind("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
        });


    });
```

Comment: This worked. Its still strange to me why only in chrome 'window' doesnt work. I'm not that experienced in jQuery and dont quite understand its inner working... guess i  need to do more reading and less writting code by trial and error :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `window` to `"form"`.

Also consider adding `e.stopPropagation();`.